# Help to create a notation!!

Tags: notation

If $A$ is an algebra and $D_1, D_2\in A$ we can define the commutator $$[D_1, D_2]:=D_1\circ D_2-D_2\circ D_1.$$

I'd like to create an analogous notation to sum up things like these:

$$D_1\circ D-D\circ D_2.$$

It must be a notation which makes sense in general.

It seems something silly, but I am going to use this in another context where expressions like this are huge and very frequent so it would be very useful to have such a notation.

Thanks.

Comment: Look at the definition of _free algebra_. Perhaps this helps.

Comment: Ok, I'll check it.